# Non-normal and inseparable extension of degree 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I know that it is possible to have a non-normal and inseparable extension of degree $pq$ for any prime $p$ and any natural number $q \ne 1$.
But is there possible to construct such extension of degree $5$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of an non-normal inseparable field extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242542/example-of-an-non-normal-inseparable-field-extension)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242542/example-of-an-non-normal-inseparable-field-extension this answer gives a example of extension of degree 15 = 3*5 and I find it does not work if let 5 = 1*5 as it would be normal extension.

Comment: I see, you have edited "$q$ not equal to $1$" now. Let me see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

Let $L/K$ be an extension of degree $5$. Take $\alpha \in L-K$. Then $K(\alpha)$ is a sub-extension of $L$, and hence $[K(\alpha):K]$ divides $[L:K] = 5$, so that degree is either $1$ or $5$. By choice of $\alpha$, it is not $1$. Therefore, this is a primitive inseparable extension generated by any element not in $K$.

Next, the extension must be purely inseparable. We have
$$[L:K] = [L:K]_s [L:K]_i$$
and you want $[L:K]_i > 1$. Just like before, the degree is $5$, a prime, and so together these require $[L:K]_i = 5$.

This means that a primitive element $\alpha$ is purely inseparable of degree over $K$ and so it has minimal polynomial  $(x-\alpha)^5$, which splits in $L$. This holds for all $\alpha \in L - K$, and obviously the minimal polynomial of anything in $K$ splits in $L$, so the extension is normal.